# C++, приватное наследование и неявное приведение типа

Tags: c++, наследование, приведение-типов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему правила `C++` запрещают неявное приведение типа при использовании приватного наследования?

Происходит ли тоже самое при защищенном наследовании?

Comment: да, происходит. А почему - ну зачем-то  приватное ставили. Видимо не просто так же.

Comment: да, тут важно знать, что  класс наследует закрыто или защищенно, значит все защищенные и открытые члены базового класса как бы  становятся закрытыми / защищенными членами производного. Только методы  производного класса(и друзья) могут  присвоить свой указатель указателью базового класса... Для защищенного наследования еще и их наследники(их методы)...

Comment: Закрытое / защищенное наследование не делает класс разновидностью базового. Производный класс не является, а  пользуется базовым классом.

Comment: Ничего они не запрещают. Закрытое / защищенное наследование также делает класс разновидностью базового. А спецификатор доступа только ограничивает область применения приведения к базовому типу. Пример `class A{}; void F(A &){} class B: A { B(){ F(*this); } };`

Comment: @user7860670, тут  F является функцие_членм, естественно она может рассмотреть  ссылться на свой обьект  через ссыльку на базовый класс. Еслибы он был разновидностью, то внешние функции тоже могли бы сделать то же самое.  Если  самолет  некоторыми атрибутами похож на  птицу, это не значит, что самолет является разновидностью птиц(он может вести себя как птица)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan *"тут F является функцие_членм"* - ээ нет, это свободная функция.

Answer (score 0):

Базовый класс у класса наследника это только часть его (рука). Когда вы разрешаете управлять внешне рукой класса, то это вы полностью доверяете удалённому управлению.

А если рука очень важна и сделана приватной, то и приватность это и делает запрет удалённого управления. А приведение типа это как раз даёт удалённое управление.

Чтобы хорошо представить принцип наследование можно посмотреть на стандартное , и именованное. Принцип одинаковый. Синтаксис чуток отличается.

```
class Base {
public :
  void Fun ( ) ;
} ;

// стандартное наследование
class Son : private Base {
public :
private :
} ;

// именованное наследование
class Son2 {
public :
private :
  operator Base & ( ) { return left ; }
  Base left ;
} ;

int main ( ) {
  Son s ;
  
  // static_cast < Base  & > ( s ) . Fun ( ) ;
  // error: ‘Base’ is an inaccessible base of ‘Son’
    
  Son2 s2 ;
  
  // s2 . left . Fun ( ) ;
  // error: ‘Base Son2::left’ is private within this context

  // static_cast < Base  & > ( s2 ) . Fun ( ) ;
  // error: ‘Son2::operator Base&()’ is private within this context
}
```